# insert some jquery code in existing javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working with some code, i had modified some code where i am doing some manipulation of selections, but i need to insert some code after the specific javascript code:

The code is

```
product.options[product.options.length] = newoption;
    switch(cSelected) {
```

i want it to be:

```
product.options[product.options.length] = newoption;
        var x = 0;
        while(x < cSelected.length){
            switch(cSelected[x]) {
```

now the identification line is:

```
product.options[product.options.length] = newoption;
```

i am trying to use insertAfter but lost how to add this

same case is the ending of the function

```
break;

    }

}
```

need to be like this:

```
break;

            }
            x++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `insertAfter` is for *DOM* changes, not JS code changes.  JS doesn't (by any sensible interpretation) support self-modifying code.

Comment: understood, what are my chances here now

Comment: your chances are close to nil.  Either find a way to make a _different_ piece of code get called, or fix the original piece of code.

Comment: @BenjaminRay You seem to be searching for misspellings of JavaScript to fix, but your suggested edits are missing loads of other typos and grammar issues in posts.  Please try to fix all spellings and grammar issues together.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source file you should make the changes directly. If not you can replace the reference with your own function declaration so that any subsequent calls to the function will execute your function. Note that any bounded references to the original function will not be overridden and will still call the original function.

```
//original
function llama() {
    product.options[product.options.length] = newoption;
    switch(cSelected) {}
}
//your new function
llama = function(){
product.options[product.options.length] = newoption;
var x = 0;
while(x < cSelected.length){
    switch(cSelected[x]) {}
x++;
}
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but won't fix any code that already has a bound reference to the original function.  Given that, it's simpler just to create a new function than to try and monkey-patch the original.

Comment: what u mean by bound reference, this will modify the parent code a bit, but still will behave the ay i need it

Comment: A bounded reference would be assigning the function to a variable. So for example if the function was refrenced directly to a click handler it would be bound to the origina:l `element.onclick = llama`. whereas if it was wrapped in a function and then called the function it would execute the new function `element.onclick = function(){llama();}`

Comment: @Austin I was thinking more of the case of an event handler that's already attached to that function.